# Update sql con PHP ¿Cómo se modifica un usuario?

Tags: php, mysql, web, update

Estoy intentando modificar un usuario registrado usando tablas para que muestre distintas informaciones pero no se modifican los cambios :( Creo que tengo un error en el UPDATE pero lo paso por phpmyadmin y no me marca error, acá les dejo el html y el php

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="form-control">
       <h2><b>Datos del asociado</b></h2>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" >
            <thead class="thead-dark" >
                <tr>       
                    <th>cedula</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>apellido</th>
                    <th>Telefóno Movil</th>
                    <th>Teléfono Fijo</th>
                    <th>Correo</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="cedula" placeholder="Nueva Cedula" value="<?php echo $cedula; ?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nuevo Nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre; ?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido" placeholder="Nuevo Apellido" value="<?php echo $apellido; ?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="movil" placeholder="Nuevo Movil" value="<?php echo $movil; ?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono" placeholder="Nuevo Teléfono fijo" value="<?php echo $telefono; ?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="correo" placeholder="Nuevo correo" value="<?php echo $correo; ?>"></td>

                <tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h2><b>Datos relacionados al cargo</b></h2>
        <table class="table table-striped  table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>Categoria</th>
                    <th>Condicion</th>
                    <th>Ordinario/contratado</th>
                    <th>Monto sueldo</th>
                    <th>desde</th>                 
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><select class="form-control" name="categoria">
                       <option ></option>
                        <option value="1">Titular</option>
                        <option value="2">Asociado</option>
                        <option value="3">Agregado</option>
                        <option value="4">Asistente</option>
                        <option value="5">Instructor</option>
                        <option value="5">Jubilado</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><select class="form-control" name="condicion" >
                        <option ></option>
                        <option value="1">Tiempo Convencional</option>
                        <option value="2">Medio Tiempo</option>
                        <option value="3">Tiempo Completo</option>
                        <option value="4">Dedicacion Exclusiva</option>

                    </select></td>
                    <td><select class="form-control" name="ordinario" >
                        <option></option>
                        <option value="1">Ordinario</option>
                        <option value="2">Contratado</option>                            
                    </select></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Monto del nuevo sueldo" name="monto" value="<?php echo $monto; ?>"></td>
                    <td><input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="desde" value="<?php echo $desde; ?>"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
        <br>

        <button type="butmit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Cambios</button> 
    </form>
```

Ahora les dejo el php para modificar

```
    if (!empty($_POST)){


        $cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];     

        $fechaContratacion = $_POST['fechaContratacion'];
        $fechaInscripcion = $_POST['fechaInscripcion'];
        $movil = $_POST['movil'];
        $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
        $correo = $_POST['correo'];
        $categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
        $condicion = $_POST['condicion'];           
        $ordinario = $_POST['ordinario'];
        $monto = $_POST['monto'];
        $desde = $_POST['desde'];       
            mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE asociado SET cedula = '$cedula', nombre = '$nombre', apellido = '".$apellido."', fechaContratacion = '".$fechaContratacion."', fechaInscripcion = '$fechaInscripcion', movil = '$movil', telefono = '$telefono', correo = '$correo', idCategoria = '$categoria."', idCondicion = '$condicion', ordinario = '$condicion'");
            mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE sueldo   SET cedula = '$cedula', desde = '$desde', monto = '$monto'");     
   }
```

No sé si a lo mejor en el update lo estoy haciendo mal, los leo. Ignoren esta parte del texto, me pedía que escribiera mas ya que era puro código, lo intenté hacer lo mas corto y rápido, espero se entienda mi duda

Comment: Pon el query sql en una vsriable y

Comment: Pues lo que yo hago es poner el query en una variable y la imprimo para ver como queda el query y lo pruebo en el sql, pero estoy viendo que no ahi ninguna condición para la actualización

Comment: cuál sería la condicion entonces?

Comment: Intenta imprimir el query y pruebalo en phpmyadmin y mira que error te sale, puede ser que este mal algun nombre de algun campo y con respecto la condicion esa la debes saber tu si queires actualizar un asociado en específico deberias buscar por un dsto unico, pon tu query en una variable e imprimela por pantalla y pruebas eso en phpmyadmin

Comment: Tienes error de sintaxis en el primer `mysqli_query`, te haces en él un lío con las concatenaciones. Para evitar esos líos puedes escribir toda la sentencia sin concatenar (sin usar el punto), usando comillas dobles al principio y al final solamente. Prueba así: `mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE asociado SET cedula = '$cedula', nombre = '$nombre', apellido = '$apellido', fechaContratacion = '$fechaContratacion', fechaInscripcion = '$fechaInscripcion', movil = '$movil', telefono = '$telefono', correo = '$correo', idCategoria = '$categoria', idCondicion = '$condicion', ordinario = '$condicion'");`

Comment: El segundo `mysqli_query` está bien, porque no te haces el lío de empezar a concatenar sin necesidad. Dicho eso, deberías considerar implementar consultas preparadas en ambos casos, pues tu código es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*.